# Jquery mobile page transitions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, transition

Hello I am trying to make my page transitions and test them a bit but they are not working when I add data-transition="something" and its not working at all can you guys have a look? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Kontrol Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.css" />
    <script src="jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script src="ajaxupload-v1.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (!strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index')) {
            $htmmm = '
                <div id="go-back">

                    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"></a>
                </div>';
                echo $htmmm;
        }
    ?>
<div id="demo1"></div>
    <ul id="menu">

        <li>
            <a class="scroll menuButton" href="index.php" data-transition="pop">Forside</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="scroll menuButton" href="menukort.php" data-transition="slide">Menukort</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="scroll menuButton" href="udstillinger.php" data-transition="fade">Udstillinger</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the pages you want to animate to have `data-role='page'` in the enclosing `<div>`? I ask because your example doesn't.

Comment: so you are saying that I need a div that wraps all the content in the pages that is with a data-role-page attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make sure each page is set up this way.

```
 <body>

 <div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Header and footer are not required

Answer (score -1):

Hy, my answer is late but it seems that *.php page is not support...
Try using *.html and it should work.

Maybe I'm wrong and in this case, **please give to us the solution**.

Regards,

Comment: Ok for -1 But please explain. This -1 means you know the solution so please give the correct way to do.. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just another requirement for the -1. Please explain why it should work with php extension ?